# Wordpress responsive layout with fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a design in my head that I want to build upon _s starter theme. The design consits of a header being floated to left with fixed positioning (it will stay on the screen no matter what). It also requires a fixed width.

I made the wide display version and it looks how I want. But here's the problem. When I reduce the browser the content-area that has a % width goes behind the fixed element. Or if I set a left-margin to it, when reducing the content is not bound by the window width because of that margin.

Is it possible to make a responsive design with fixed positioning? I was thinking grid systems like Bootstrap but reading around I don't think that will solve it either.

Comment: Can you provide some code and/or an example of the problem? It's not very clear.

Comment: Have you thought about adjusting the size(width) of the fixed element when the window size drops below a certain width?